# Blender exporter - "uncaught syntaxError unexpected token" THREE.JSONLoader()

Tags: three.js

Have you come across this erro: `"uncaught syntaxError unexpected token"`

When loading a model exported from Blender 2.63a with the three exporter addon?

From this code copied from three.js github example

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( {"buffalo.js", function(geo){createModel(geo)}});
```

Thanks
Regards
Chris

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you been able to solve this?

Comment: "uncaught syntaxError unexpected token" should specify the token, moreover, use "OBJLoader" instead of "JSONLoader()".

Answer (score 3):

Check whether the model has a material. Search in `buffalo.s` for the string: `"material"  : ,`. If you find that string, your model has no material assigned - bad syntax error appears! Go to blender, assign material, and export again to `buffalo.js`.

Not working:

```
...
"objects" :
{
"Monkey" : {
    "geometry"  : "geo_Monkey",
    "groups"    : [  ],
    "material"  : ,
    "position"  : [ -0.150241, 5.41906, 2.96394 ],
    "rotation"  : [ 0.874236, 0.0220203, -3.11527 ],
    "quaternion": [ 0.00726118, 0.0155444, -0.423137, -0.905903 ],
    "scale"     : [ 2.9257, 2.86503, 2.68207 ],
    "visible"       : true,
    "castShadow"    : false,
    "receiveShadow" : false,
    "doubleSided"   : false
},

...
},
...
```

Working:

```
...
"objects" :
{
"Monkey" : {
    "geometry"  : "geo_Monkey",
    "groups"    : [  ],
    "material"  : "Material",
    "position"  : [ -0.150241, 5.41906, 2.96394 ],
    "rotation"  : [ 0.874236, 0.0220203, -3.11527 ],
    "quaternion": [ 0.00726118, 0.0155444, -0.423137, -0.905903 ],
    "scale"     : [ 2.9257, 2.86503, 2.68207 ],
    "visible"       : true,
    "castShadow"    : false,
    "receiveShadow" : false,
    "doubleSided"   : false
},

...
},
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by leaving out the JSON signature of the load function. Like this:

loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

```
    loader.load( 'buffalo.js',function( geo )
    {
....
```

Hope this helps
Regards